# Does it make sense to use perfmon in a vSphere infrastructure?

Tags: windows, vmware-vsphere, performance-monitoring, vmware-vcenter, perfmon

vCenter has its own performance counters, so does it make sense to use perfmon to baseline or monitor things like IOPS of Windows VMs, or should I just be using vCenter counters instead?

Would perfmon counters even be accurate for these VMs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course it would.  Why wouldn't it?

There's nothing saying you can't use both perfmon *and* vCenter counters to monitor the performance of your VMs - perfmon is better at or easier to set up for some metrics, and vCenter's counters are for other metrics, so it makes sense to use whichever one fits better for the specific metric and purpose you're monitoring.

And yes, perfmon counters are accurate for virtual machines as well as physical ones. Depending on what, precisely, you're wanting to monitor, the virtual machine may or may not have access to the information you're wanting, though.  If you wanted to monitor IOPS by LUN on a SAN-backed virtual machine, you'd have to use the vCenter counters, of course, but if you just wanted total IOPS (to see if some application is hammering the disk, or like that), then perfmon would be perfectly capable of accurately monitoring for that purpose.